# Aurelia contact-manager not loading modules

Tags: aurelia

I'm following the contact-manager tutorial. Have added bootstrap and jQuery dependencies and the no-selection ts and html;however when app starts I see a different message in console to that expected in the tutorial text:

```
ERROR [app-router] Error: Load timeout for modules: no-selection
```

followed by

```
ERROR [app-router] Router navigation failed, and no previous location or fallbackRoute could be restored.
```

Code looks like this:

app.ts:

```
    import {Router, RouterConfiguration} from 'aurelia-router';

export class App {
  router: Router;

  configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router){
    config.title = 'Contacts';
    config.map([
      { route: '',              moduleId: 'no-selection',   title: 'Select'},
      { route: 'contacts/:id',  moduleId: 'contact-detail', name:'contacts' }
    ]);

    this.router = router;
  }
}
```

app.html:

```
<template>
  <require from="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></require>
  <require from="./styles.css"></require>


  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
        <span>Contacts</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">Contact List Placeholder</div>
      <router-view class="col-md-8"></router-view>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

dependencies added to aurelia.json:

```
 "jquery",
          {
            "name": "bootstrap",
            "path": "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist",
            "main": "js/bootstrap.min",
            "deps": ["jquery"],
            "exports": "$",
            "resources": [
              "css/bootstrap.css"
            ]
          },
```

no-selection.ts

```
export class NoSelection {
  message = "Please Select a Contact.";
}
```

no-selection.html:

```
<template>
  <div class="no-selection text-center">
    <h2>${message}</h2>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Can you add any code / link to jsfiddle?

Comment: Did you add the no-selection module to the `src` directory? Right now, I can't see any error in the code you posted.

Comment: The no-selection.ts and no-selection.html files are in the src directory. The only thing I can recall that isn't exactly as the tutorial is that I installed the latest version of jQuery, Could that have an effect?

Comment: I renamed all the no-selection artefacts to remove the dash and it all worked. More oddly - continuing the tutorial and adding further things with dashes (e.g. contact-list) works fine too.

Comment: I think I'm having a similar problem, only the error message is different: `Unable to find module with ID: no-selection` :(